# Centered layout with the sidebar extension to the right of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a fixed layout, with the sidebar's background extend to the far right. I drew a sketch to illustrate the image:

[image]

how would I go about extending the sidebar background to extend till the end of the right screen, on any window size? I tried with:

```
#sidebar {
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/sidebar-base.png) no-repeat 0 -8px;
    min-height: 200px;
    &::after {
        content: '';
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        background: url(../img/sidebar-rx.png) repeat-x 0 -9px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

but a scroll would appear horizontally, and if I apply `overflow:hidden` on the body I wouldn't be able to scroll to the bottom. Thank you!

**EDIT**: I did try to find my luck with javascript but there's still a little scroll:

```
$(function(){
    $sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    $sidebar.css({width: window.innerWidth - ($sidebar.offset().left)})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem lies only in the scrolling, you can easily fix this with this line

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

and applying it to the background's parent or the body element altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyone following here or not? anyway, I think you should static position and hidden overflow like below:

```
#sidebar {
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        margin:0;}
```

Also to hide the scrolls, you should hide your body overflow too.

Hope to be right and helpful...

Answer (score -1):

Set body to 100%

```
body {
height: 100%;
}
```

Then set the sidebar height to "height: auto;". That will make it extend to the height of the viewport. From there, add fixed positioning like you said.

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
overflow-y:hidden
```

That should get rid of the scroll bar across the bottom.

I would also then use a lot of right hand padding in the sidebar to extend it out.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the sidebar width to 30% and the content to 70%.

Comment: that only changes the element inside the container

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is create a wrapper div.

```
<div class="sidebar-parent">
  <div class="sidebar"><!-- Stuff Here --></div>
</div>
```

Your document should look like this when finished:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Experiment</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .content {float: left; width: 49%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;}
    .sidebar-parent {float: left; width: 50%; background-color: green;}
    .sidebar {width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="sidebar-parent">
    <div class="sidebar"><!-- Stuff Here -->blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The main thing to remember is the container div "sidebar-parent" is what's getting the width and containing the background.

To center them you'll need `width: 50%;` parent containers for both content and sidebar. You make those `float:left;` to fill the screen and then the content child container `float: right;` and the sidebar child container `float: left;` within their parent containers.

Summary: 2 50% width containers each containing 1 child container. Stack the parents together with a left float and then position the fixed width child containers within their parents.

That will center them and now you'll have the ability to have extended backgrounds.